# Arduino Serial.print() optimization

Tags: c, serial-port, arduino

```
unsigned long current_millis_value = 0;
unsigned long previous_millis_value = 0;
unsigned long m = 0;
unsigned int seconds = 0;
unsigned int minutes = 0;
unsigned int hours = 0;

unsigned long clockTimeStart = 1800000; //30 Minutes
unsigned long currentClockTime;

void loop() {
    current_millis_value = millis();
    currentClockTime -= current_millis_value - previous_millis_value;
    previous_millis_value = current_millis_value;

    minutes = (currentClockTime / 1000 / 60);
    seconds = (currentClockTime / 1000) % 60;
    m = (currentClockTime % 100);

    Serial.print(minutes);
    Serial.print(":");
    Serial.print(seconds);
    Serial.print(":");
    Serial.println(m);
}
```

I'm getting a gap in times between serial writes of anywhere from 9-11 ms per serial line written. Is there a way to optimize the `Serial.print()` method to allow writing of multiple values across types of long and String values?

Example (this is not valid but along the lines of what I'm thinking):

```
Serial.print(minutes + ":" + seconds + ":" + m);
```

I know this isn't JavaScript I'm working in - just looking for optimization possibilities for the writing process. I know that MOD can be expensive but just doing the simple subtraction and writing out the value of **currentClockTime** leaves me with a gap time of 6-7 ms.

Comment: Did you look at the output on an oscilloscope to see when the gap occurs?  That could help narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The arduino has a semi-java like string concatenation. I have no idea if this will get you any speed up, but it will concatenate everything into one string before sending it.

```
String package = "" + minutes;
package += ":"+seconds;
package += ":"+m;
Serial.print(package);
```

If you're able to reconstruct the string on the other side, perhaps a better course of action is to use `Serial.Write` and send the raw data, then reconstruct the String on the receiving side. This would reduce the amount of data you send each loop from 5-10 bytes to 3-4 bytes.

Comment: I agree with your comment that the buffer would be a cleaner solution. But the time it takes to allocate that buffer and fill it with information actually takes longer (1-2ms) than your solution. While your is not the perfect solution for my needs it is a start. Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: The benefit of a buffer is that you'd only need to allocate it once, as well as not needing to allocate it at the time you're using it. I haven't tested it out specifically, but that's something you could try out.

Answer (score 4):

Any way to pre-convert everything to a string value so you can write out the entire string at once?  For instance, use something like a `snprintf()` function to write into a pre-allocated `char[]` that you then print out in one call to `Serial.print()`?

So for instance:

```
char buffer[32];
snprintf(buffer, 32, "%u : %u : %lu", minutes, seconds, m);
Serial.print(buffer);
```

--Jason

Comment: The drawback of using any variant of printf() is that your code size will increase ~1-2KB.

Answer (score 4):

The [Streaming](http://arduiniana.org/libraries/streaming/) library should do what you want:

```
Serial << minutes << ":" << seconds << ":" << m;
```

Answer (score 1):

The fastest and preferred way to do string concatenation under Arduino is,

- Use the String class.
- If you really need the speed and/or simply want to avoid creating new in-memory strings with every concatenation operation, **reserve the needed memory ahead of time with reserve()**.
- First, set the object to an empty string "".
- Then, append the needed characters or strings by invoking concat() or the operator +=, **using exactly one concat() or += operation per line of code**. This is to avoid the creation of temporary Strings objects.
- By executing reserve() in advance, the String object will be effectively acting as a line buffer.

By applying the above guidelines, **the concatenation operations will be done in place**.

Note that reserve() should be called with the most appropriate value for the line buffer capacity, i.e.: maximum number of characters you need before String does a realloc(), not including the null-terminating character '\0'.

Three alternatives follow:

1) Here is the sample code,

```
// Declaration, outside setup() and loop()
String line;

// Inside setup()
// Use the appropriate value for reserve(), depending on on your actual usage.
line.reserve(10);

// Inside loop()
line = "";
line += minutes;
line += ":";
line += seconds;
line += ":";
line += m;
Serial.println(line);
```

2) As an alternative to calling reserve() at setup(), you could declare and initialize the String with a "template" or dummy string which has the desired (maximum) length.

Here is the sample code for this alternative,

```
// Declaration, outside setup() and loop()
String line = "XXXX:YY:ZZ";

// No need to use reserve() inside setup()

// Inside loop()
line = "";
line += minutes;
line += ":";
line += seconds;
line += ":";
line += m;
Serial.println(line);
```

The first approach allows you to use reserve() with a dynamically calculated maximum length value, while the second approach results in somewhat cleaner to read code when you have a "template" or known fixed length for the string you will be later composing.

3) **If you only need to output the data to the output stream (usually Serial), this is the fastest and the most compact code, with no need of String or external libraries,**

```
// No need to declare a String outside setup() and loop()
// No need to use reserve() inside setup()

// Inside loop()
Serial.print(minutes);
Serial.print(":");
Serial.print(seconds);
Serial.print(":");
Serial.println(m);
```

Note: the answer by John Y does exactly the same as my last piece of code, except for his "simpler" to read code (assuming you feel comfortable with the operator <<, used as C++ streaming syntactic sugar). In some cases, however, using the Streaming library will generate slightly larger/slower code.

Comment: The drawback of using the String library of Arduino is that your code size will increase ~1-2KB. By directly applying print()/println() to Serial, you can avoid this increase in code size.

Answer (score 0):

I found the easiest way to Serial print a single string composed of integers and your words (message):

in scketch :

```
int w = 12;

Serial.Print ("my number is: ");

Serial.Print (w);

Serial.Println (" - which is to be used in calculation!"
```

RESULT:

On serial monitor you will see (as a single LINE!!!!!!!!!!):

my number is: 12 - which is to be used in calculation!